# Transform property before Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I need to transform my property (remove white space on a string) first before applying validation.

Specifically I want to check if a string is part of a enum but the string may contain whitespaces (which enums don't allow far as I know)

Something like...

```
RuleFor(x => x.Value).IsEnumName(typeof(EnumType))
```

(x.Value should have whitespaces removed first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FluentValidation method `Transform` is designed for this case. The following uses the basic white space remover from Everson's answer:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Value)
  .Transform(x => x.Replace(" ", string.Empty))
  .IsEnumName(typeof(EnumType));
```

I'd opt to go with a stronger white space remover that catches tabs etc

```
RuleFor(x => x.Value)
  .Transform(x => new string(x.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray()))
  .IsEnumName(typeof(EnumType));
```

No need for a custom validator (e.g., `Must`) and personally I'd avoid writing one unless there was no other way.

I'd pop that white space remover into an extension (MVP, you should handle the null case; my preference would be a null guard but that's another topic):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveWhiteSpace(this string target){
        return new string(target.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
    }   
}
```

Then the rule is a lot more readable:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Value)
  .Transform(x => x?.RemoveWhiteSpace())
  .IsEnumName(typeof(EnumType))
  .When(x => x != null);
```

Something to be aware of: I found that if `Transform` returned `null` the `IsEnumName` rule will pass. Personally I don't like that so I'd include a `When` rule builder option to only test when `Value` is provided, or a not empty rule to ensure it is provided.

Working LINQPad sample:

```
public enum EnumType
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

public class Foo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class FooValidator : AbstractValidator<Foo>
{
    public FooValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Value)
            .Transform(x => x?.RemoveWhiteSpace())
            .IsEnumName(typeof(EnumType));
            .When(x => x != null);
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string RemoveWhiteSpace(this string target)
    {
        return new string(target.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).ToArray());
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var validator = new FooValidator();

    var foo1 = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = "Value 1" };
    var result1 = validator.Validate(foo1);
    Console.WriteLine(result1.IsValid);

    var foo2 = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = "Value2" };
    var result2 = validator.Validate(foo2);
    Console.WriteLine(result2.IsValid);

    var foo3 = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = "Value    3" };
    var result3 = validator.Validate(foo3);
    Console.WriteLine(result3.IsValid);

    var foo4 = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = "This is not a valid enum value" };
    var result4 = validator.Validate(foo4);
    Console.WriteLine(result4.IsValid);

    var foo5 = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Value = null };
    var result5 = validator.Validate(foo5);
    Console.WriteLine(result5.IsValid);
}
```

[image]

EDIT:

As per your additional comment about wrapping all of this into an extension:

```
public static class FluentValidationExtensions
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> IsEnumTypeMember<T>(this IRuleBuilderInitial<T, string> target)
    {
        return target
            .Transform(x => x?.RemoveWhiteSpace())
            .IsEnumName(typeof(EnumType))
            .When(x => x != null);
    }
}
```

Then update the rule to use it:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Value).IsEnumTypeMember();
```

This is just an MVP, I don't really know all of your use cases; you may want to make it more generic so you could apply it to other enums.

Comment: is it possible to move this to a extension method and a .when clause? (to check validation only if value is not null)

Comment: Yeah you could do that; I've added an example extension to the answer.

Comment: Cannot chain `.Transform` to `RuleFor` in .NET 4.8, with version 10.3.6 of FluentValidation

Comment: Sidenote: you can replace white-spaces with `Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", "");`

References:

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=\s&i=mind+the+gap

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#WhitespaceCharacter

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom method

```
 RuleFor(x => x.Valor).Must(BeEnumType);
```

...

```
      private bool BeEnumType(string v)
      {
        return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(EnumType), v.Replace(" ", string.Empty));
      }
```